# Filtering image gallery

Tags: jquery

I want to make a page with many images. On top of the page I want to filter them with multiple checkboxes. I want to be able to filter using one or multiple in same time.

How do i put 2 tags on same image so if a image have a dog and a cat to be show both ways?

https://jsfiddle.net/ur0jcLbf/23/

```
$("#gallery1 input").on("change", function() {
    $("#gallery1 img").css("display", "none");
    $("#gallery1 input:checked").each(function(idx, item) {
        $("#gallery1 img[data-tag='" + item.value + "']").css("display", "inline");
    });
});
```

Comment: The values of your checkbox doesn't match with the `src` of images.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ur0jcLbf/21/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```js
$(function() {
  var $gallery = $("#gallery1");
  $inputs = $gallery.find("input");
  $inputs.attr("checked", "checked");
  $inputs.on("change", function() {
    $inputs.each(function(i, cb) {
      if (!cb.checked) $gallery.find("." + this.value).css("display", "none");
    });
    $inputs.each(function(i, cb) {
      if (cb.checked) $gallery.find("." + this.value).css("display", "inline");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="dog">Dog
  <input type="checkbox" value="cat">Cat
  <input type="checkbox" value="bird">Bird
  <input type="checkbox" value="cute">Cute
  <br>
  <!-- DOG -->
  <img class="dog" src="https://image.ibb.co/ev36Dx/1.jpg">
  <img class="cute dog" src="https://image.ibb.co/cyXNmH/2.jpg">
  <!-- CAT -->
  <img class="cat" src="https://image.ibb.co/d3Rttx/3.jpg">
  <img class="cat" src="https://image.ibb.co/npueYx/4.jpg">
  <!-- Bird -->
  <img class="bird" src="https://image.ibb.co/mZE2mH/5.jpg">
  <img class="cute bird" src="https://image.ibb.co/iWaWfc/6.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi please update your code with this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<body>
<div id="gallery1">
        <input type="checkbox"value="dog">Dog 
        <input type="checkbox"value="cat">Cat 
        <input type="checkbox"value="bird">Bird
  <!-- DOG -->
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/ev36Dx/1.jpg" data_cat="dog">
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cyXNmH/2.jpg" data_cat="dog">
        <!-- CAT -->
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/d3Rttx/3.jpg" data_cat="cat">
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/npueYx/4.jpg" data_cat="cat">
        <!-- Bird -->
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/mZE2mH/5.jpg" data_cat="bird">
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iWaWfc/6.jpg" data_cat="bird">
    </div>
<script>
        $("#gallery1 input").on("change", function() {
            $("#gallery1 img").css("display", "none");
            $("#gallery1 input:checked").each(function(idx, item) {
                                $("#gallery1 img[data_cat*='" + item.value + "']").css("display", "inline");
            })
        })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! How do i put 2 tags on same image so if a image have a dog and a cat to be show both ways?

Comment: first please run this code is it full fill your requirement or not?

Comment: i think this will answer your new query

Answer (score 0):

Check it, put dog cat and bird images in seprate div with div id dog, cat, bird:->

```
/* check box ids*/
var idArray = ['dog_1', 'cat_1', 'bird_1'];
/* check checkbox status */
function changeStatus(event){
    var ids = checkedSelection();
    var lengthOfIds = ids.length;
    for(var index = 0; index < lengthOfIds; index++){
   var elm = ids[index].slice(0,ids[index].length-2);
                 console.log(elm);
       $("#"+elm).show()
    }       
}

/* filter checked check box*/
function checkedSelection(){
var newIds = [];
for(var index = 0; index < idArray.length; index++ ){
  var el=document.getElementById(idArray[index]).checked;
  el ? newIds.push(idArray[index]) : $("#"+idArray[index].slice(0,idArray[index].length-2)).hide();
}
    return newIds;
}
```